# Get selected value in dropdown list that is populated dynamicaly using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

here i am trying to display a country flag when a currency is selected but my code is not working when i use data from the API

JS

```
function createDoll(userChoice) {
var output = document.getElementById("display_here");
output.innerHTML = "";

var links = [
    "https://simplytest.co.za/fxpaymaster/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/usd-flat.jpg",
    "https://simplytest.co.za/fxpaymaster/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/sa-flag.jpg"
];
var img1;
var e=document.getElementById("currency-from");
var strUservalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var strUsertext = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
if(strUservalue=='USD')
{
     img1 = '<img src="' + links[userChoice] + '">';
}

var choices = ["USD", "ZAR"];
var sentence = choices[userChoice]
var img1 = '<img src="' + links[userChoice] + '">';

output.innerHTML = sentence +img1 +strUservalue;
```

here is my HTML

```
<body>
  <input type="text" name="" id="currency-from-text" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Transferring how much?" value="1">
                            <select class="populate-currencies" id="currency-from" onchange="createDoll(this.value)">
                        <option value="USD" id="curr">USD</option>

                        </select>
</body>
```

i want if someone select USD the US flag displays,
if they select GBP the UK flag displays

Comment: I removed the PHP tag from your question since it's unrelated

Comment: "_but my code is not working when i use data from the API_" What does "is not working" mean, white page, wrong flag? What API?

Comment: Hi  kerbholz, thanks for your reply, when you select a currency it says undefined and the broken image shows instead of the flag

Comment: `<img src="' + links[userChoice] + '">'` Does your array `links` have an element with key `USD`?

Comment: here is the array i am using 
var links = [
    "usd-flat.jpg",
    "sa-flag.jpg"
];

Answer (score 0):

`links[USD]` doesn't exist. Change your `links` array to an associative array:

```
var links = {
   "USD": "https://simplytest.co.za/fxpaymaster/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/usd-flat.jpg",
   "SA": "https://simplytest.co.za/fxpaymaster/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/sa-flag.jpg"
};

<select class="populate-currencies" id="currency-from" onchange="createDoll(this.value)">
  <option value="USD">USD</option>
  <option value="SA">SA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if i use it this way it works but the problem is i am using value on the  <option value="0">USD</option> to get the selected currency for me to convert the data and the value is coming as plain text. links[USD]
  <select class="populate-currencies" id="currency-from" onchange="createDoll(this.value)">
         <option value="USD" id="curr">USD</option>
</select>

Comment: Edited my answer. Actually, I'll just remove the first part

Comment: when i use it the way you show me above, the icon is no longer showing

Comment: What icon are you talking about? Is it because I removed the `id="curr"` from the `option`?

Comment: when a user select  USD for example this *** /2019/09/usd-flat.jpg need to be displayed. it was showing a placeholder icon before but when i use an array like this
var links = {
   "USD": "***/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/usd-flat.jpg",
   "SA": "***/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/sa-flag.jpg"
};
it doesnt show any icon

Comment: I don't see any code related to changing/setting an icon or placeholder, sorry. Any chance you put in some effort and try to fix that yourself? Or maybe ask a new question?

Comment: <select class="populate-currencies" id="currency-from" onchange="createDoll(this.value)">
                        <option value="USD" id="curr">USD</option>

                        </select>
i fixed the problem by using this.selectedIndex instead of this.value

thanks alot for helping